# Conditional formatting based on two view models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to apply a style based on conditions in multiple view models.

For example, I have a list of items that can be conditionally formatted at the item level, but I also want to be able to turn the formatting on or off at the whole list level:

Main view model

```
class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ParentViewModel ()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> {
            new ChildViewModel{ Display = "I am red", Format=1 },
            new ChildViewModel{ Display = "I am red", Format=1 },
            new ChildViewModel{ Display = "I am blue", Format=2 },
            new ChildViewModel{ Display = "I am blue", Format=2 },
        };
        ShowFormatting = false;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Items { get ... }

    // I would like to use this property to turn formatting off for the whole list
    public bool ShowFormatting { get ... } 
}
```

Contains many sub-view models

```
class ChildViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public string Display { get ... }

    public int Format { get ... }
}
```

Displayed in a window

```
<Window ...>
  <Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
<!-- How can I access ShowFormatting from the main view model here? --> 
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Format}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Format}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<!-- Or can I apply the conditional formatting here? -->
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"></TextBlock>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem that I see is that the style is targeting a `ChildViewModel` and the `ShowFormatting` property is not accessible. The best solution that I can come up with is to have a backlink from the `ChildViewModel` to the `ParentViewModel`, but having backlinks generally seems bad to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `RelativeSource` for your Binding? (I'm assuming here that the DataContext of your Window is of Type `ParentViewModel`)

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Format}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Format}" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowFormatting, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="SomeValue">
        <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="SetToThisValue"></Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: I think you need `...{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}...`. My data context was set slightly further in the than the window, but this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to have two different child view models, `ChildViewModel1` and `ChildViewModel2`. The `ParentViewModel` would populate `Items` with one or both of these types: you could use an `ObservableCollection<object>` if you wish. When you define a datatemplate for `ChildViewModel1` and another for `ChildViewModel2`, then depending which child view model was resident in the `ObservableCollection`, you'd get the respective rendering.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I purposely simplified the example above (I always find it difficult to get the balance between simplifying enough to make it understandable but not miss out too much). In my real example I have a left and right list - left items should not be formatted, and items can be moved between the lists.